# Why is selenium telling me I'm missing a paranthases in my javascript code when I'm not?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

This is the code I'm currently using in my selenium application.

```py
container_xpath = '//a[starts-with(@href, "/direct/t/")]/../../..'

def js_code(code = ""):
    return f"document.evaluate('{container_xpath}', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; {code}"

code = f'console.log(\"{js_code()}\")'
self.driver.execute_script(code)
```

Output of js_code():

```
document.evaluate('//a[starts-with(@href, "/direct/t/")]/../../..', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

This all looks fine to me, however, when I run this I'm getting an error thrown into the terminal: "selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list". Ty for any help!

Comment: What does “js_code” output?

Comment: @evolutionxbox document.evaluate('//a[starts-with(@href, "/direct/t/")]/../../..', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

Answer (score 1):

While defining a Xpath you can't use double quotes ("")
so try changing it form from "/direct/t/" to '/direct/t/'

if that too doesn't seem to work then change the entre statement from

'//a[starts-with(@href, "/direct/t/")]/../../..'

to

"//a[starts-with(@href,'/direct/t/')]/../../.."

Comment: Are you sure? I've used double quotes before in chrome and it works fine.

Comment: This wasn't the solution to my problem